# Если в компоненте изменится локальный state перерисует ли дочерние компоненты?

Tags: reactjs, state

Код:
После вызова setTimeOut стейт меняет свое состояние

```
function App() {
 const [test, setState] = useState(0);

 setTimeOut(() => setState(1), 1000);

return (
  <>
   {test}
   <Component />
   <ComponentTwo />
  </>
);
}
```

Перерисуются ли дочерние компоненты?

Comment: Попробуйте проверить опытным путем и расскажите нам о наблюдениях)

Comment: передав пропсом стейт в один из компонентов и вызвав в console.log, он вызвался 2 раза, т.е все таки он перерисовывает себя и свои дочерние компоненты

Comment: Конечно. Ведь компонент - это и он сам и его наследники.